# Ardour, system has a limit for maximum amount of locked memory

Tags: ram, xubuntu, ulimit, ardour

After installing and starting [Ardour](http://ardour.org/) I receive the following warning message:

> WARNING: Your system has a limit for maximum amount of locked memory.
>   This might cause Ardour to run out of memory before your system runs
>   out of memory.
>
> You can view the memory limit with 'ulimit -l', and it is normally
>   controlled by /etc/security/limits.conf

How to configure properly [Ardour](http://ardour.org/) to avoid this message?

Answer (score 7):

Launch a terminal (CTRL-ALT-T) and open the file in gedit with admin priveldges:

```
sudo gedit /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Be sure that the file contains the following line:

```
@audio - memlock unlimited
```

If it doesn't exist, add it. If it does exist, be sure the line doesn't begin with a `#` and is below any other lines in the file beginning with `@audio`. This will allow any user in the `audio` group to avoid memlock limits. Save, close the editor, then add your user to the group by running the command

```
sudo adduser $USER audio
```

Close the terminal, log out and back in again, and reopen Ardour. The message should be gone.

Comment: I fixed this code window.. needed a dash.  Thanks for the tip.. it works now.  You can test this with ulmit -l

Comment: The above didn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.10. instead I followed these directions. The narration is in German but the commands are all the same ... https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Tonstudio/Konfiguration/#Echtzeitrechte-fuer-die-Benutzergruppe-Audio

Comment: @somethis yes, we have to add `@audio - memlock unlimited` with the dash, it looks like a mistake in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a warning you can safely ignore it. However to change it, open the file `/etc/security/limits.conf` with an editor. You'll find a line there which reads:

```
@audio - memlock SOME_NUMBER
```

You can comment out this line (put a `#` in front of it) or change `SOME_NUMBER` to the word `unlimited`. Now Ardour should not spit out a warning.

Comment: Nice! I will give it a try this week since I have a recording session. Thanks!

Comment: Unlike many warnings, it is NOT TRUE you can ignore this warning. When recording in real time with Ardour, if you run out of memory, it will affect the recording. I would not say you can " safely ignore it" . For this reason I am downvoting this answer.

Comment: What does it mean?  Why it only appears in this software and not Chrome for example?